# display success message with clear the post data and redirect on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one web page. In that I have contact form.
What I want that after submit the form it should redirect on same page and display success message(message should be fadeout after few seconds) and the post data of form should be clear. In form i am also cheking verification code and sending mail.

```
if(md5($_POST['vcode']).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon'])
    {
        $msg="message";

        $to      = 'test@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'subject';
        $message = $msg;
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .="From: ".$_POST['email']." \r\n";

        $mail=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if($mail==true)
        {
            echo '<script>$("#deletesuccess").fadeIn();$("#deletesuccess").delay(4000).fadeOut();window.location="index.php";</script>';
          //here i want to redirect on same page with clear post data and display success message.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("disp_wrong_code").style.display="inline";</script>';
         // This is verification code error.
    }
```

This is custom php page.

Comment: I tried this.... I write my code

Comment: Please give me the code or example  !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For redirecting you can use `header` function. For storing data between page loads use `$_SESSION`. Some simplified example:

```
session_start();
if ($can_do_post)
{
    // do some actions here
    $mail=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mail==true) {
        // set SESSION to know that it's success result
        $_SESSION['form_filled'] = true;
        // redirect to the same page
        header("Location: /script.php");
        die();
    }
}
else
{ 
    // no post data here
    // check session:
    if (isset($_SESSION['form_filled']) && $_SESSION['form_filled']) {
        echo '<script>$("#deletesuccess").fadeIn();$("#deletesuccess").delay(4000).fadeOut();window.location="index.php";</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: missing `session_start();` perhaps? `;-)`